# Angular 2 Data service updating observable

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have an app and I'm getting some Observable Objects through a data service. 
This is my code:

```js
  this.currentUser$ = dataService.getUser(authService.id);
      this.currentUser$.subscribe(user => {
        this.currentUser = user;

        this.classes = dataService.getClasses(this.currentUser.school, this.currentGroup);
        this.activities = dataService.getActivities(this.currentUser.school, this.currentGroup, this.currentClassId);


      });
```

This works when the page first loads, but there's a button that should update the Class ID so the page display the activities from the previous class, but I can't find a way to update the observable so I can get the data from another class.

Comment: You can update an observable with observer. It's probably only the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the button's click event, use event binding to bind to a method of the component. In that method, call the getActivities service method. So something like this:

```
getActivitiesForClass() {
    this.activities = this.dataService.getActivities(this.currentUser.school, this.currentGroup, this.currentClassId);
}
```

Comment: I tried this before and it didn't work, I tried again with "this.activities = this.dataService.getActivities(this.currentUser.school, this.currentGroup, this.currentClassId);" and now it does. Thank you.